# How to set all cookies with a single max_age in pylons?

Tags: cookies, pylons

Normally, we set the cookie with a single `max_age` as following:

```
response.set_cookie('name1', 'value1', max_age=3600*24*365)
response.set_cookie('name2', 'value2', max_age=3600*24*365)
response.set_cookie('name3', 'value3', max_age=3600*24*365)
```

Note, we set the `max_age` again and again. How to set a **default max_age** to all cookies that does not have a max_age parameter? Is there any configuration for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be simple wrap set_cookie function:

```
def set_cookie(name, value, max_age=DEFAULT_MAX_AGE):
   response.set_cookie(name, value, max_age)
```